# Microsoft graph api - Fetching events returns funky subject

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I suspect that there might be a bug in the graph Api.

I have a Powershellscript that fetches events for a series of meetingrooms.

the URL i use: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*roomuserid*/Events? 
 $Filter=start/datetime ge '2018-10-29'"

the response looks like it should(in Json format), but however, on some events(but not all) the subject field seems to also include the name of the organizer.

For example: if John Doe books a meeting in meetingroom 1, with the subject "Meeting1", the graph api would sometimes return the subject as "John Doe Meeting1" where i expected it to be just "Meeting1".

Has anyone else encountered this, or seen similar behavior with the Graph Api?

Edit:
Subject field is covered, as it contains the name of a user. but as you can see, the response looks good, it just appends the name of the user to the subject.

[image]

Comment: Could you include an example of the bad response that you are seeing?

Comment: Done. i'll try to create a meeting with test data to be shared here.

Comment: did you found a solution for this?? I'm having a similar problem, but in my case I'm getting only the name of the organizer in the subject field :/

Comment: No, sadly, i did not. However, i made a workarround, where i searched for the organizer name in the subject feld, and trimmed it out if i found a match.